# I have a error in Django html file where the IF statement is not working properly

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a like button and I want it to show an already liked button if the user has already liked the post. Here is my html:

```
    {% for post in posts %} 
        <div class="border-solid border-2 mr-10 ml-10 mt-3 px-2 pb-4">
            <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold mt-2 mb-2"><a href="/user/{{post.User}}">{{post.User}}</a></h1>
            {% if post.User == request.user.username %} 
                <button id="btn_{{post.id}}" type="submit">Edit</button>
                <div id="text_{{post.id}}" class="hidden">
                    <textarea required="" maxlength="300" class="border-solid border-2 w-full h-20" name="text" id="textarea_{{post.id}}" cols="30" rows="10">{{post.Content}}</textarea>
                    <button id="btn1_{{post.id}}" class="bg-blue-600 rounded-lg px-4 py-2 mt-1 text-white">Confirm</button>
                </div>
                <script>
                    document.querySelector('#btn_{{post.id}}').addEventListener('click', function() {
                        document.querySelector('#Content_{{post.id}}').className = "hidden";
                        document.querySelector('#text_{{post.id}}').className = 'block';
                    })
                    document.querySelector('#btn1_{{post.id}}').addEventListener('click', function() {
                        fetch('/edit/{{post.id}}', {
                            method: "POST",
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                content: document.querySelector('#textarea_{{post.id}}').value
                            })
                        })
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(result => 
                        document.querySelector('#p_{{post.id}}').innerHTML = result.Content
                        );

                        document.querySelector('#Content_{{post.id}}').className = "block";
                        document.querySelector('#text_{{post.id}}').className = 'hidden';
                    })
                </script>
            {% endif %} 
            <div id="Content_{{post.id}}">
                <p id="p_{{post.id}}" class="text-xl">{{post.Content}}</p>
                <input id="" type="hidden" value="{{post.Content}}">
            </div>
            <p>{{post.Date}}</p>
            {% if post.User != request.user.username %} 
                <button id="btn3_{{post.id}}"> like
                </button>
                <script>
                    document.querySelector('#btn3_{{post.id}}').addEventListener('click', function() {
                        fetch('/like/{{post.id}}', {
                            method: "post",
                        })
                        .then(response => response.json())
                                .then(result => 
                                document.querySelector('#likes_{{post.id}}').innerHTML = result.likes
                                );
                    })

                </script>
            {% endif %}
            {% if post.id in has_liked %}
                <button class="btn4_{{post.id}}"> Unlike
                </button>
            {% endif %}
            <p id="likes_{{post.id}}">{{post.likes}}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is the views.py function:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.POST['text']
        user = request.user.username
        now = datetime.now()
        time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        
        Post.objects.create(
            User = user,
            Content = text,
            Date = time,
            likes = 0
        )

        return redirect("/")
    
    p = Paginator(Post.objects.all().order_by("id").reverse(), 10)
    posts = p.get_page(request.GET.get('page'))
    likes = Like.objects.all()
    has_liked = []

    try:
        for like in likes:
            if like.user == request.user.username:
                has_liked.append(like.post)
    except:
        has_liked = []


    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "posts": posts,
        "has_liked": has_liked
        
    })
```

I tried checking the the values of both has_liked which returned '1' and the value of post.id which returned 1. So I don't know what went wrong as Both the values are the same except one is a string

Answer (score 0):

String and integer value are not same in python. As you mentioned, **has_liked** returned **string '1'** and **post.id** **returns int 1**. First convert **post.id** to string. To to that you can use django's built in template tag **slugify**. Try this code:

```
{% if post.id|slugify in has_liked %}
    <button class="btn4_{{post.id}}"> Unlike
    </button>
{% endif %}
```